# How to just input 'y' without having to press ENTER?

Tags: bash

Using this portion of a bash script as an example

```
{   
    read -p "Do you want to update the tv feed? [y/n/q] " ynq
    case $ynq in
    [Yy]* ) rm ~/cron/beeb.txt; /usr/bin/get-iplayer --type tv>>~/cron/beeb.txt;; 
    [Nn]* ) echo;;
    [Qq]* ) exit;;
    * ) echo "Please answer yes or no. ";;
    esac
}
```

How do I get it so that you can press <kbd>y</kbd> and not have to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> for it to be accepted please?

Comment: You can specify how many characters you want to read with `-n`. First result when searching btw.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add `-n 1` to the `read` command's options. From the bash manpage:

```
-n nchars
    read  returns after reading nchars characters rather than
    waiting for a complete line of input.
```

BTW, you should also double-quote `"$ynq"` -- sometimes users *will* just press return, which can cause weird behavior if the variable isn't double-quoted. Also, note that `read -n` is a bash extension, so make sure you're using bash (i.e. `#!/bin/bash` or similar for the first line of the script), not a brand-x shell (`#!/bin/sh` or similar).

Comment: Yes, it is #!/bin/bash, but that was just part of the script, but thanks very much, its working now :)

Answer (score 6):

Use `-n1` with `read` to specify max number of input length to 1:

```
read -n1 -p "Do you want to update the tv feed? [y/n/q] " ynq
```

Answer (score 3):

I am on Mac and using `read -n1 $user_decision` doesn't do the trick for some reason in `bash`, `sh`, or `zsh`. So, I am using this which works across all:

```
 #!/bin/zsh

 # -k1 = First char pressed without waiting, for /r or /n.
 # -t3 = timeout for 3 seconds
 # -s = prevent outputting the input back to stdout.
 echo "Press any letter..."
 read -t3 -k1 -s user_decision

 # Prints 1st arbitrary keypress entered during 3s timeout     
 echo $user_decision # EG: "y", or "n" for instance.
```

To simplify, you can just use `read -k1 user_decision` to get precisely what you requested set into the value for the variable name `$user_decision`, without waiting for `/r` or `/n` (hitting enter or return).